# Is there a query to find all objects where a certain directory is used by

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to find all objects on an instance that use a certain directory.

It seems that this info is not available in the all_dependencies view.

Has anyone an idea?

Comment: Do you mean external tables (which you can see in `all_external_tables`), or stored code that uses a directory via e.g. `utl_file`? Directory names are passed as arguments, so you get runtime errors if they don't exist (or you don't have privs) at that point; you won't get compilation errors, so there is no fixed dependency. I don't think PL/Scope would track this either. So I don't think you can find references without scanning through all the source code - in `all_source` or your source code repository...

Comment: Thank you alex i need both external tables and all other stored code. Your hint to all_sources solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query for a quick report of all the external tables and all other jobs where the name of the directory is mentioned

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    gr.grantee                          schema,
    dir.directory_name                  directory,
    dir.directory_path                  path,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT et.table_name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP(
    ORDER BY
        et.table_name
    )                                   external_tables,
    LISTAGG(DISTINCT als.name
                     || nvl2(als.name, ' (', NULL)
                     || als.type
                     || nvl2(als.name, ')', NULL), ', ') other_objects
FROM
         all_directories dir
    JOIN all_tab_privs       gr ON dir.directory_name = gr.table_name
    LEFT JOIN all_external_tables et ON dir.directory_name = et.default_directory_name
    LEFT JOIN all_source          als ON gr.grantee = als.owner
                                AND lower(als.text) LIKE '%'
                                                         || lower(dir.directory_name)
                                                         || '%'
WHERE
        gr.type = 'DIRECTORY'
    AND gr.grantee != 'SYS'
GROUP BY
    grantee,
    directory_name,
    directory_path
ORDER BY
    grantee ASC,
    directory_name ASC
```